# Power supply rated for "140 watts with natural convection" - Does it need a fan?

Tags: power-supply, fan, cooling

In the data sheet for my CUI VOF-225C power supply, under mechanical, it is mentioned that :

cooling - natural convection (no integrated fan)

Does this mean I do not need to run a fan with my power supply? It has two JST PHR pins where I can connect a 12 volt fan. I imagine these pins are controlled to come on under some temperature condition, and it is simply included in the PSU as an optional feature.

Comment: This is a question you should be asking the vendor.  They designed the part and know all about it, whereas no one here is likely to have specific knowledge about that product.

Answer (score 2):

If the datasheet says it can do 140W with natural convection, in theory you don't need a fan.  Note that reliability will improve if you can keep the supply temperature low, so if you can install a fan it should increase the lifetime of your supply.

I have tested many power supplies that are "optimistic" about their power output and have actually failed at rated power with high (but in spec) ambient temperatures.  CUI is a reputable vendor though and I would trust what they say.

Comment: thanks! typically, will the fan be always on when the supply is on, or will it only come on when the temperature is high?

Comment: only the datasheet or the manufacturer would be able to tell you that, Oscar.

Comment: The datasheet doesn't specify anything other than the fan voltage, my assumption would be that it's on all the time.  You could find a thermal switch if you only wanted it to run at higher temperatures.